# Getting ID of a Div by the class, Nested Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

In my **ASP.NET MVC 4** project I want to add **dynamically divs**, and divs in those divs
But when I have 1 div in another div, they have to be linked with an **ID**
My problem is not knowing how to get that ID in **Javascript**, *i'm quit noob at it*.

Here some code, it's a partial view with an important **a tag**, When I look at the **compiled HTML, the ID's in the div with attribute child_container are correct**.

```
@model Evaluatietool.Models.Resultaatsgebieden

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("listRG"))
{
<div parent_container="y">
    <div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SysteemVanRG)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SysteemVanRG)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SysteemVanRG)
        <div id="@ViewBag.ID" child_container="y" class="RIs">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="add-concretiseringRG">Add another</a>
</div>
}
```

The javascript

```
$('.add-concretiseringRG').live("click", function (e) {
    var append_obj = $(this).parent().find("div[child_container=y]");
    var id = $('.RIs').id;
    $.post('@Url.Action("GetNewRI")',{id: id}, function (data) {
        append_obj.append(data);
        });
    });
```

The problem is in the javascript, I want to get the **ID** of the **div with attribute child_container**, but it's **undefined** when I Alert it.

Comment: No, child_container is correct, that's the place where I want to append the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to get the id of element with class `RIs` which is same as the `append_obj` object.

Change

```
var id = $('.RIs').id;
```

to

```
var id = append_obj.attr('id');
```

Comment: `.id` can be used consistently across  browsers to get the id from a plain DOM element but you used it on a jQuery object. `$('.RIs')[0].id` or `$('.RIs').get(0).id` would have worked as well

Comment: @DavidFregoli in that case it should be `append_obj[0].id`